# jQuery if statement for two select items

Tags: jquery, select, if-statement

If two select elements are set to a "yes" I want a `<div>` to show. This code works for one of them but how do I add a second "if"?

```
<select id="select1">
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
</select>
<select id="select2">
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
</select>

$('#select1').change(function() {
    if($(this).val() == 'Yes') {
        $('#divtest').show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:

```
var a;
var b;

$('#select1').change(function() {
    a =$(this).val();
    if(a=='Yes' && b=='Yes') {
        alert('yes')   
    }
});

$('#select2').change(function() {
    b =$(this).val();
    if(a=='Yes' && b=='Yes') {
        alert('yes')   
    }
});
```

See the example here: https://jsfiddle.net/L25rean4/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#select1').change(function(){
    test()});
$('#select2').change(function(){
    test()});

function test()
{
    if($('#select1').val() == 'Yes' && $('#select2').val() == 'Yes'){
        alert("test");}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a change event on both, then in that event check to see if both are set to yes:

```
<select id="select1" class='select'>
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
</select>
<select id="select2" class='select'>
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
</select>

<div class='test'></div>

$('.select').change(function () {
    if ($('#select1').val() == 'Yes' && $('#select2').val() == 'Yes') {
        $('.test').addClass('yes');
    }
    else {
        $('.test').removeClass('yes');
    }
});
```

The [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/5agx3wft/4/) shows this in action.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like stated below. Every time you change the value of one of the two select fields, it checks if the values are both "Yes". If that's the case, it shows the div. When one (or both) of the fields are changed back to "No", it checks again. This results in a "Yes" and "No" thus it hides. Try it out:

```js
$('#select1, #select2').on('change', function() {
  if ($('#select1').val() === 'Yes' && $('#select2').val() === 'Yes') {
    $('#divtest').show();
  } else {
    $('#divtest').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1">
  <option value="No">No</option>
  <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
</select>
<select id="select2">
  <option value="No">No</option>
  <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
</select>

<div id="divtest" style="display:none;">TestDiv</div>
```